# Terminating a postgresql's process but it is still there

Tags: postgresql

Terminating a postgresql's process but it is still there

[image]

Is there any way to kill it forcefully?

Comment: cancel just cancels the backend, use `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` to kill it

Comment: @VaoTsun thanks, that worked. if you write it as answer, i will mark your answer as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

> **pg_cancel_backend(pid int)**    *returns boolean*
>   Cancel a backend's current
>   query. This is also allowed if the calling role is a member of the
>   role whose backend is being canceled or the calling role has been
>   granted pg_signal_backend, however only superusers can cancel
>   superuser backends.
>
> **pg_terminate_backend(pid int)** *boolean*
>   Terminate a backend. This is
>   also allowed if the calling role is a member of the role whose backend
>   is being terminated or the calling role has been granted
>   pg_signal_backend, however only superusers can terminate superuser
>   backends.

Formatting mine

Use `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` to kill process